# Books to relearn basic and mental math, for someone taking the MCAT?

Tags: reference-request

I am a pre-med student who has always been weak at math and had a lot of anxiety surrounding it. The only math I was ever good at was introductory statistics.

I need to take the MCAT exam and quickly solve math equations, but even my basic math skills are trash. For the purposes of the test, I just need to ballpark numbers--but I'd prefer to re-build from the ground up. I've looked at [this book](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/the-trachtenberg-speed-system-of-basic-mathematics-jakow-trachtenberg/1104696734?ean=9784871877091/)!, but it doesn't look user-friendly.

Please keep in mind I'll be self-teaching this and am already incredibly weak at math. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Girlfriend (also studying for MCAT) is using this. I've had the book prior and it is a gem.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0307338401/ref=sxts1?ie=UTF8&qid=1474401865&sr=1&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_QL65](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0307338401)

Comment: Awesome. I love Benjamin's routine. Thanks for the input.